# Need alerg for this indicator

Tags: pine-script

I would like to add and alertcondition for buy or sell when all the ma have the same color
For example for buy green and lime and for sell marron and red

Can someone please help me with it?

This is the indicator code:

https://www.tradingview.com/script/n4rW85zV-Madrid-MA-Ribbon-Bar-v2/

Comment: Please do not post a link to code, please post the code (or minimum amount to get the same error) that is not working in the question.

Comment: Please check out [tour], [ask] and [mcve] on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the lines you want to compare, you might use something like this:

```
shouldAlertSell = maColor(ma10,ma100) == red and leadMAColor == red
alertcondition(shouldAlertSell, "Sell Alert")
```